# Скорость работы алгоритма на C#

Tags: c#, linq, tpl

Есть такая задачка простенькая. Подсчитать количество повторений строковых элементов в неотсортированных коллекциях. Коллекции от 200 тыс. элементов.

До этого мало работал с TPL в C#. Реализация работает конечно быстрее однопоточной версии, но всё равно очень долго, около **3 мин**. (на 4-х ядерном Core i7)

```
        List<string> _list = new List<string>();
        Dictionary<string, int> _dictionary = new Dictionary<string, int>();
        Parallel.For(0, _list.Count, i => {
            int cout = 0;
            for (int j = 0; j < _list.Count; j++) {
                if (_list[i] == _list[j]) {
                    cout++;
                }
            }
            lock (_dictionary) {
                if (!_dictionary.TryGetValue(_list[i], out int value)) {
                    _dictionary.Add(_list[i], cout);
                }
            }
        });
```

Потом переписал с помощью LINQ. Как итог скорость работы около **100 мс**.

```
 var counts = (from note in WordsList
               group note by note into g
               select new { Note = g.Key, Count = g.Count() }).ToDictionary(key => key.Note, val => val.Count);
```

Вот собственно вопрос. За счет чего такая большая разница в скорости работы?

Answer (score 1):

Ну у Вас же словарь не используется должным образом, а только служит хранилищем.

Приведённый алгоритм квадратичный, поскольку сравнивает все элементы со всеми

Псевдокод со словарём (почти линейный, если словарь - хэш-таблица):

```
 for (int i = 0; j < _list.Count; i++) 
     if (_dictionary.TryGetValue(_list[i], out int value)) 
           _dictionary.SetValue(_list[i], value + 1);  
    else
         _dictionary.Add(_list[i], 1);
```

Comment: Сначала ведь мне нужно сгенерировать словарь, для этого нужен код выше.
Словарь типа: "слово" - "кол-во повторений".

И вопрос всё таки был немного в другом. Почему LINQ выражение намного быстрее делает ту же работу? И что можно изменить в первом фрагменте кода, чтобы повысить его производительность?

Comment: Ну я переформулировал в более похожих на Ваши операциях, может, так будет яснее. А почему быстрее -  вроде сказал: линейный алгоритм (порядка n операций) быстрее квадратичного (n*n операций)

Comment: Наверное, тебе стоит почитать про оценку сложности алгоритмов, если ты не понял ответ MBo...